# .gdbinit 'set startup-with-shell off' doesn't work for gdb 8.3: [New Thread 0x1303 of process 2451]

Tags: macos, gdb

I was using gdb 8.3 on MacOSX 10.14.6 Mojave.

I had conquered the code signing issue by following the procedure:
https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/PermissionsDarwin

(Pasting the issue statement here for others to search and fix.)

```
   Unable to find Mach task port for process-id 57304: (os/kern) failure (0x5).
   (please check gdb is codesigned - see taskgated(8))
```

But my later issue is '~/.gdbinit' does not work for gdb.

GDB would start 'New Thread' for the debugged program:

`~/.gdbinit` content: `set startup-with-shell off`

````
```
   Reading symbols from a.out...
   Reading symbols from /Users/zong/GitRepos/local/test-gdb/a.out.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/a.out...
   (gdb) b 4
   Breakpoint 1 at 0x100000f66: file a.c, line 4.
   (gdb) run
   Starting program: /Users/zong/GitRepos/local/test-gdb/a.out
   [New Thread 0x1103 of process 1905]
```
````

After searching, instead of `~/.gdbinit`, we can explicitly appoint .gdbinit file for gdb to use, like `gdb -x ~/.gdbinit <executable file>` (for VSCode, set `"miDebuggerArgs": "-x ${workspaceFolder}/.gdbinit"` in `launch.json`).

My question is why `~/.gdbinit` doesn't work?